# get value embedded b/w comments in xml using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to parse xml document with a certain format. The issue rises when I have values of the tags embedded b/w comments, e.g.

```
<document>
    <field loc="field1">field name 1</field>
    <field loc="field2"><!--this is a comment-->field name 2<!--also a comment--></field>
</document>
```

I can get the value for field1 but when I try to get the value for field2, it fails:

```
/document/field[@loc='field2']
```

any help will be appreciated. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `/document/field[@loc = 'field2']` should suffice to find the string value of that field, independent of the presence of any comments inside the element. Or do you want to select the comments as well?

Answer (score 0):

From DOM Code, you can access comments or values, they appear as child nodes like everything else (node type NODE_COMMENT value 8).

```
function listComments( ndField ) {
    var i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < ndField.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
        switch( ndField.childNodes[i].nodeType ) {
            case 3: // element
                WScript.Echo( "Element Text: " + ndField.childNodes[i].text );
                break
            case 8: // comment
                WScript.Echo( "Comment Text: " + ndField.childNodes[i].data );
                break
        }
    }
}


try {
    var xml = new ActiveXObject( strDOMObject );
    xml.load( "test.xml" );
    var i = 0;

    var ndFields = xml.selectNodes( "//field" );
    for( i = 0; i < ndFields.length; i++ ) {
        listComments( ndFields[i] );
    }
```

From XSLT, use the XSL comment() function to get comments, or just the value:of for the actual value.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select='//field'>
        <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
        <xsl:value-of select="comment()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps...